# Another word for highlighting text

Tags: single-word-requests

I came across a word recently, something like: underline / highlight part of text. Really simple definition, but the word seemed unusual to me.

I made a mental note of the word, but didn't write it down, now forgot and it drives me crazy for 3 days now. Thesaurus and onelook reverse dictionary are not helping. Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: Emphasize, stress, underscore, feature, bring to light, accentuate, point up?

Comment: annotate?  select?

Comment: @LubošMotl - Rather than *point up*, I would use *point out*.

Comment: @Graffito - 'Point up' works for me.

Comment: @aparente001 - if you compare google results for "point out a sentence" and "point up a sentence" (using quotation marks), you will see more than 300 000 results for "out" and nothing for "up".

Comment: @Graffito - Indeed, "point out a sentence" is a common phrase.  But it doesn't mean "highlight a sentence".  It means to draw someone's attention to a sentence.  For example, a professor might write some stuff on the board and then say, "Before I prove the theorem, I'd like to point out something unusual about the theorem statement."

Answer (score 0):

Luboš Motl's first suggestion is the one that I would make: **emphasize**. When quoting someone else, you will sometimes see portions of the text underlined, italicized, or bold-faced, with a disclaimer following that reads, "**Emphasis** mine."

On the other hand, I was looking up the reasons why portions of user agreements are written in all-caps. The reason? All-caps is used to **make** those portions **conspicuous**.